# I want to develop a framework in Python for desktop based applications. How should I go about it?

Tags: python, frameworks, desktop

I want to develop a desktop application framework in Python, much like QT, but how to go about it? Any tutorials or links related to it would be helpful!

Comment: I don't get the question.  Do you want to write an application or a framework?  The title says "develop a framework" but the question says "develop ... application".  Which is it?

Comment: a framework , which helps in developing applications . hope you get it now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the best way to start is to look at the source code of the framework the other answers are talking about.

First, try to use them all to build the same application with the functionalities you expect from a framework. Them, look at how it works under the hood.

Secondly, build your framework, starting by writing your first widgets, then notice the problems with your current architecture, and re factor. Start again, until you have something stable and usable.

Eventually, find out this was nice as training experience, but useless as a contribution to the software communities since you will never reach out the qualities of existing tools.

Then give up and try to code your own MMORPG.

Answer (score 4):

There is so many great freameworks like [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/download.php#binaries) ([Tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20Learn%20wxPython)), [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) ([Tutorial](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials)), [PyGtk](http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html) ([Tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/tutorial.html)) already.

You just need to try your favorite one.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a pretty comprehensive list of Gui programming frameworks for Python here, http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Answer (score 2):

theres WxPython tutorial http://www.wxpython.org/tutorial.php

or PyQt http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/

or the ever stylish Tk http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/